# iOS8 SearchController SearchBar Prompt overlapping with placeholder text

Tags: swift, ios8, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

Working with search controller in iOS8 using Swift, I am trying to add a prompt to the SearchBar but it overlaps with the placeholder text.

```
searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 235.0/255.0, green: 73.0/255.0, blue: 27.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search your restaurant"
searchController.searchBar.prompt = "Quick Search"
```

Screenshot at https://www.dropbox.com/s/lawqm0mqxc60fyt/Screenshot%202014-11-26%2002.40.10.png?dl=0

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910089/uisearchbar-prompt-not-displaying-properly/53284893#53284893