# UISearchBar 'prompt' Not Displaying Properly

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I have setup a UISearchBarController like so:

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.searchBar.prompt = @"Searching Transactions Since Nov 11 2017";
self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
```

This is the output of setting `.prompt`:

[image]

That is how it looks when the view presents and during scrolling. The `prompt` should be showing above the search bar, as seen in [the HIG](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/bars/search-bars/).

Does anyone know why it might be doing this? Is it a bug? Or is the `prompt` only meant to show properly when setting a separate search controller?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is a bug on UISearchBar, but you can add offset:

```
self.searchController.searchBar.searchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0, 20);
```

And in case you have cancel button:

```
UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil];
[cancelButton setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, 20) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```